# 15 W USB ports in car

Tags: usb, charger, telephone

My car has two 15 W USB C ports that will fast charge my phone, but they are not powerful enough to super fast 2.0 power my phone (S21+).  Is there any kind of device that would take the two 15 W outputs and combine them to one 30 W output for super fast charging?

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to get a separate charger, **specifically for that device**, that fits the car's accessory ("cigar lighter") socket.

1. Putting two voltage voltage-regulated supplies in parallel will **not** split the load evenly, because there are manufacturing tolerances. if one puts out 5.00 volts, and the other 5.01 VDC, the higher-voltage supply would tend to provide *all* the current, or even drive the lower-voltage supply.
2. The device to be charged needs a specific "handshake", i.e., specific signals and impedances at the charging port, so that the device can charge at the faster rate. Simply having the power *available* would not make it charge faster.